# Lost Numeric coordinate Information in R

Tags: r, dataframe, coordinates

I have a huge .csv data frame with 1205289 rows and 42 columns. The only way that I can read the data was using:

```
df<-read.table("dataframe", header = T, sep = "\t", fill = T)

head(df) #showing only long lat values

  decimallatitude decimallongitude 
     38.8993         -94.7437                            
     42.7439         -89.1281                            
     42.7439         -89.1281                            
     41.5462         -70.6159                            
     35.105          -106.576                            
     42.5287         -83.4516
```

I need extract only the columns about longitude and latitude occurrences:

```
x<-df[,long:lat]
```

When check the x it's observed that the values not correspond to coordinate.

```
decimallatitude decimallongitude 
      73778            167432 
      110745           153103 
      110745           153103 
      99038            75071 
      53888            8670 
      108703           132473
```

I have sought some ways to fix it, but I can't find.

Comment: what is the `str()` for those two variables?

Comment: As hinted by Sotos, it is likely that your variables have been read in as factors. The `str()` function would verify this. I'd recommend adding the as.is=TRUE argument to your `read.table` function and then inspecting the contents of your lat and long vars.